# Need help troubleshooting source of memory leak - C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am getting some sort of memory leak with this code. Although is doesnt actually throw any error, when run through Memcheck, it detects a memory leak.

Am I supposed to also delete[] the temporary array or something?

Here is the function it is happening in:

Comment: The code is missing from your question.

Comment: When you [edit] your question to add the code, you should also show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Every memory allocation needs to be paired to exactly one deallocation. When this function ends, the memory pointed to by `newBinaryNum` has not been deallocated, and the address of that memory is not retained anywhere. Hence, memory leak.

Since you don't use any benefits of dynamic allocation for this `BinaryNum` object, don't use dynamic allocation. Just declare your variable as `BinaryNum newBinaryNum;`. Not only will the compiler handle the memory needs of this object, but also your code would be able to benefit from [return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).

(Also, you should lean on the standard library a bit more. Your manipulations of `binaryAry` mimic the functionality of [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Why re-invent the wheel? Your focus in this function should be on the `BinaryNum` class, so delegate the memory management details to the standard library.)

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention that since this is for an assignment, we are not permitted to use std::vector and such. how would i deallocate newBinaryNum since i need that value until it is returned?

Comment: @Bob Don't deallocate it. Don't allocate it. Just declare it as a local object and let the compiler handle the details.